# Django doesn't see static files

Tags: python, django

So the thing is that django simply can't recognize the static files. No matter what have I tried it just doesn't work. I tried changing the from global searching way to a direct url of the css file, none of this seems to work.

The structure of my project looks like this:

[image: structure]

Here is my code:

```
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'django.contrib.admin',
   'django.contrib.auth',
   'django.contrib.contenttypes',
   'django.contrib.sessions',
   'django.contrib.messages',
   'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from something.views import *
    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', home),
        ]
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Monkeys</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/file.css' %}"/>
        </head>
```

Could find the answer in any topic on the internet so I'm hoping you could help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Did you run `python manage.py collectstatic`? Also, does the problem occur in debug or live mode (or both)?

Comment: Yea, as it should bee

Comment: From what I see, you have already collect the static files.

Comment: Please post generated file url from rendered page, try to open it manually and post the error message/http status it will return. Also `print(STATIC_ROOT)`.

Comment: "GET /static/css/file.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1761 - Thats the error, but where can i put the print cmnd so it won't give me another error with an undefined variable ?

Comment: In settings.py is fine. `settings.STATIC_ROOT` would work almost everywhere.

Comment: It's giving me that adres ---->/Users/ivanizumov/Desktop/environment/static_cdn

Comment: Is your file there `/Users/ivanizumov/Desktop/environment/static_cdn/css/file.css`?

Comment: Nope, it's in the separate directory, okay than,  another question - how can i redirect the search to another folder? Also I've tried to put my css file into /Users/ivanizumov/Desktop/environment/static_cdn that directory - didn't work, my project still can't find it, although its in that folder

Comment: Show full path to this file wherever it is. And please answer the question from the first comment: is DEBUG=False or True in your case? Are you running on dev or prod conf?

Comment: /Users/ivanizumov/desktop/environment/practice/static/css thats the path to my file and yes, my DEBUG is on true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have a typo - **STATIC_DIRS** instead of **[STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS)**, so collectstatic is not configured at all currently.

Fix it, then run `collectstatic` again.

Comment: Actually, its pointing the right place, cuz when i tried the second option of yours it gave me an error like this --> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/ivanizumov/Desktop/environment/practice/practice/static'

Comment: Right, I did not notice `os.path.dirname`. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

[Go some steps back and set up static files and make sure it follows exactly django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/)

[Only about static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#static-files)

[This project has similar structure as yours](https://github.com/Belonias/personal-site)

When collectstatic is run, the default STATICFILES_FINDERS value django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder will collect your static files from any paths that you have in STATICFILES_DIRS.

The other default STATICFILES_FINDERS value django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder will look in the /static/ folder of any apps in your INSTALLED_APPS.

All of the static files that are found will be placed in the specified STATIC_ROOT directory.

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static_cdn")
```

You can also use python manage.py findstatic to see which directories collectstatic will look in.

```sh
manage.py findstatic
```