# How to Setting Up Django Static Files?

Tags: python, css, django, django-staticfiles

So for settings up my django static files I added these code in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_DIRS = [
 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

So I created A static folder In Base Directory and then I created a folder named css inside of it and I added a file named nav.css into it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/nav.css' %}">
```

But it's not working at all. It gives me error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

What I did wrong?

Comment: post folder structure

Comment: did you try `python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: what about assets folder then?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django don't see static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55441919/django-dont-see-static-files)

Comment: So what I did actually, I made static folder inside an app. And it works fine. But even now I didn't get the philosophy difference between  how it works inside of folder or outside of folder.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
```